# R: Function varies the length of its output when used with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, user-defined-functions

I have the problem, that the use of a user-defined function in data.table varies the functions output. I have constructed a simple version which has the same problem:

```
library(data.table)

tmp.f <- function(Date.v){var.v <- Date.v }

dt1 <- data.table( Date = c("2018-05-15","2018-05-16") )
dt1[, tmp := length( tmp.f(Date.v = Date)) ]

dt2 <- data.table( Date = c("2018-05-14","2018-05-15","2018-05-16") )
dt2[, tmp := length( tmp.f(Date.v = Date)) ]

dt1
#         Date tmp
#1: 2018-05-15   2
#2: 2018-05-16   2

dt2
#         Date tmp 
#1: 2018-05-14   3    
#2: 2018-05-15   3    
#3: 2018-05-16   3
```

I would need the function to simply pick up the respective date from the Date column in the data.table and calculate the corresponding value (in this example the same date). The length of the function output should always be 1. But somehow it seems to pick up the column length.

(The example is just constructed to show the problem that I have within a larger function)

Thank you very much.

Comment: The entire variable is being passed to your function. It would feel more natural to use `by`, should you be able to fit it into your workflow.

Comment: Thank you so much Roman for the fast reply - this is exactly what solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Roman, you can use `by` to obtain the desired output:

```
dt2[, tmp := length( tmp.f(Date.v = Date)), by = Date ]
```

Functions like `length`, `sum` or `max` take vectors as inputs but return single values. What happens in your example is that your column `Date` is entirely passed to `tmp.f` then to `length` which will output 3 as a single value. It is then recycled to fill the `tmp` column, giving the impression that `length( tmp.f(Date.v = Date))` has been computed for each row while it has only been computed once.

Using `by` or not will mainly depend on whether the function you apply is naturally vectorized (or in the case of `cumsum`, outputs vectors of same length):

```
 dt2[, tmp := as.Date(Date) + 10] # works as expected because function(x){as.Date(x)+10} 
                                  # is naturally vectorized
```

Comment: Thank to very much kluu, for the explanation and the solution. This solves exactly the problem for the short version of the problem, and now my overall function also works based on your logic. Really great.

Comment: @user9938203 the best way to say "thank you" on stackoverflow is by upvoting answerer's answer. :)

Comment: Thank you - the system tells me I have too little reputation (upvote will be registered but does not change the number). But thanks for the hint, and the answer helped a lot